# "Cannot insert duplicate key" when using Automapper to map to an existing Entity Framework entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, automapper

I am trying to update a database row by reading the entity (using Entity Framework 6), mapping new properties onto that entity (using AutoMapper) and then calling `context.SaveChanges()`.

The problem I am having surrounds the navigational properties within my entity. It appears that during the mapping, a new object is being created and assigned to the navigational property, rather than the existing one's properties simply being updated.

Here's are my domain objects:

```
public class ParagraphComponent : IReportComponent
{
    public Guid ComponentId { get; set; }
    public float LineHeight { get; set; }
    public ReportTextList TextItems { get; set; } = new ReportTextList();
}

public class ReportTextList : IList<ReportText>
{
    private readonly IList<ReportText> _list = new List<ReportText>();

    public int Count => _list.Count;
    public bool IsReadOnly => _list.IsReadOnly;

    // Overrides for IList...
    public void Add(ReportText item) 
    {
        _list.Add(item);
    }

    // ...Remove(), Insert() etc.
}

public class ReportText
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Entity Framework entities:

```
public partial class ParagraphComponentEntity
{
    public System.Guid ComponentId { get; set; } // ComponentId (Primary key)
    public double LineHeight { get; set; } // LineHeight
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ReportTextEntity> ReportTexts { get; set; } 
}

public partial class ReportTextEntity
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; } // Id (Primary key)
    public string Content { get; set; } // Content
}
```

**What I am doing**: I am taking data for a `ParagraphComponent` from an API endpoint to perform an update. I load the existing component based on `ParagraphComponent.Id` and then I map the new properties onto the existing entity.

This works fine:

```
public async Task<bool> EditComponent(IReportComponent editedComponent)
{
    var currentParagraphComponentEntity = await Context
        .ParagraphComponents
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ComponentId == editedComponent.ComponentId)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    Mapper.Map(editedComponent as ParagraphComponent, currentParagraphComponentEntity);
    
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I can see in debug that the properties are mapped correctly, but when `SaveChanges()` is called I get the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ReportText'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ReportText'

It appears that the mapping process is assigning a new object to the `ParagraphComponentEntity.ReportTexts` property, thus Entity Framework sees it as an "Add" rather than an "Update", so it tries adding a new row to that table which errors because of the primary key enforcing the Id to be unique.

My AutoMapper configuration:

```
CreateMap<ParagraphComponent, ParagraphComponentEntity>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LineHeight, src => src.MapFrom(s => s.LineHeight))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ReportTexts, src => src.MapFrom(s => s.TextItems))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ComponentId, src => src.MapFrom(s => s.ComponentId))
    .ForAllOtherMembers(src => src.Ignore());
```

If AutoMapper is creating a new instance for the `ReportTexts` navigational property is the issue, how do I get around it?

Comment: A database that has a primary key will only allow one row with the key.  When key exists you need to use Update instead of Add.

Comment: @jdweng I know. The question isn't about that. If I were updating the entity manually (e.g. `myComponent.LineHeight = 123` then calling `Context.SaveChanges()`) it would work, but the fact that I am using AutoMapper is giving an issue with the navigational property.

Comment: You need to check if key exists and then based on results use either Update or Add.  you are using ADD.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code which is fetching data from database is only fetching the main resource `ParagraphComponent`. Collection of `ReportTexts` by default will not be fetched into EF context because as far as I know EF is lazy loading - you need to eagerly load referenced entities with `.Include(..)` for instance.

If I am right - then before mapping your data into entity `ReportTexts` collection is empty and your Mapping code is really creating new items in that collection. These entities are comming from outside of EF context (read about EF ChangeTracking) so 'it' thinks that these are new entities which needs to be inserted into database. These objects obviously already contains `Id` set with existing keys - so that's where you get conflicts.

I think if you will eager load your entity, then EF should perform Update instead

Comment: Thanks for the response and you were correct, it was not loading the `ReportTexts` from the DB. I have updated my DB read to be `Context.ParagraphComponents.Include(x => x.ReportTexts)...`.  However, I am still getting the exact same error. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to check if your mapping code is replacing old items (from db) and putting new objects in. I am not sure what Automapper will do here. But for testing purposes you could ignore for a moment mapping ReportTexts property in Mapper configuration. If It will not throw exception - then it will confirm what I said

Comment: Yeah that is what I suspect is happening. If I get AutoMapper to ignore the `ReportTexts` property (so my AutoMapper config is normally `.ForMember(dest => dest.ReportTexts, src => src.MapFrom(s => s.TextItems))`, whereas if I comment that out and let the `.ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.Ignore())` ignore it) then it works - I can save the component with the new data fine. It seems like AutoMapper just replaces the navigational properties with a new instance rather than updating the existing instance. There does not appear to be any option to prevent it from doing this.

Comment: I can see there is an extension for that https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection Honestly I would suggest not using automapper for such things. Automapper configuration get very complex and very hard to debug. For few years I prefer to write explicit mapping code.